# VBA scraping giving all values in a string instead of single values

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I'm having a problem when scraping a certain page.
Usually this method works fine but in this case its not working as intended

I'm trying to extract single value an put each one in different cell but the application outputs whole row as single string.

Values have been obscured

[Page snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7X2E.png)

```
Set Data = html.getElementById("function-4300006681") 'Sweeper [4300006681]
Set tr = html.getElementsByTagName("tr")
Set td = html.getElementsByTagName("td")
Set Table = html.getElementsByTagName("tbody")



For Each tr In Table
    row = row + 1
        For Each td In tr.Children
        col = col + 1
        PPR_IBPS.Cells(row, col).Value = td.innerText
    Next td
   col = 0
Next tr
```

any ideas what I'm missing? its a problem wit the <a tag or the empty values? any guidance appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If found a solution myself after hitting the wall with all direction so i post it if its useful for someone :)

```
Set Data = html.getElementById(func)
Set tr = html.getElementsByTagName("tr")
Set td = html.getElementsByTagName("td")
Set Table = html.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
Set tditem = html.getElementsByTagName("td").Item()

For Each tr In Data.Children
    For Each td In tr.Children
    row = row + 1
        For Each tditem In td.Children
        col = col + 1
        'Debug.Print tditem.innerText
        PPR_IBPS.Cells(row, col).Value = tditem.innerText
        Next tditem
        col = 0
    Next td
Next tr
```

Basically just looped another time for each item in td with another variable using .item()